# get the exit code for python program

Tags: python

I'm running a python program on WindowsXP.  How can I obtain the exit code after my program ends?

Comment: how are you planning to do this?

Comment: @phoenix24 you should go back to questions you have previously asked and mark the right ones as answered.  Your acceptance rating is quite low. 44%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a Windows command line you can use:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

For example:

```
C:\work>python helloworld.py
Hello World!

C:\work>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

Answer (score 5):

How do you run the program?

Exit in python with sys.exit(1)

If you're in CMD or a BAT file you can access the variable %ERRORLEVEL% to obtain the exit code.

For example (batch file):

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LABEL
```

Comment: IF ERRORLEVEL 1 will match exit codes of >= 1 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576

Answer (score 4):

You can also use python to start your python-program

```
import subprocess
import sys
retcode = subprocess.call([sys.executable, "myscript.py"])
print retcode
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ERRORLEVEL (as opposed to %ERRORLEVEL%) to [check for a specific exit value](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576) use

```
IF ERRORLEVEL <N> IF NOT ERRORLEVEL <N+1> <COMMAND>
```

For example

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO LABEL
```