# Showing or leaving python error messages when running them by batch

Tags: python, batch-file, batch-processing

To simplify, I have batch file which runs multiple python programs:

```
start "01" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" test1.py
start "02" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" test2.py
```

But I found that even if test1.py is not run because of its error, it simply moves on to run test2.py.

It even just closes the window for test1.py as soon as it confronts that error, and just creates another window for test2.py

Of course, if I run test1.py separately by running

```
python test1.py
```

then it prints all error messages.

Since I have tens of python files in one batch, it becomes very hard to know which one of these caused the error, and I can't even know what's that error because I can't see the error messages.

How can I make it stop (but not closes the window) when it meets some error, and shows me the error message?

Comment: Have you tried exception handling? https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: You could also make some loggers to put all the error messages into a text file. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging

Comment: @moarCoffee Hmm.. how should I change my batch code to get the log file of all python programs that the batch file ran? When I run it, I see windows like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-TXZSZXR3SVBoS1E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know much about **Python**. But according to the question it outputs messages to stdout and stderr which only console applications do.

But if `python.exe` is indeed a console application and not a Windows (GUI) application, it is not really necessary to use `start "title" /wait` as this just results in calling console application `python.exe` in a separate command line interpreter process which is the reason why there is no output of `python.exe` displayed in command line interpreter process in which is executed the batch file.

I suggest to simply try:

```
@echo off
echo Calling Python with script test1.py.
"C:\python27\python.exe" test1.py
if errorlevel 1 pause
echo Calling Python with script test2.py.
"C:\python27\python.exe" test2.py
if errorlevel 1 pause
```

For error handling, see for example:

- [Exit codes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285289/exit-codes-in-python)
- [get the exit code for python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491796/get-the-exit-code-for-python-program)
- [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576)
- [Correct Testing Precedence of Batch File ERRORLEVELs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/39585)
- Windows documentation for command [If](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx)

Please use the search feature of Stack Overflow explained on help page [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and also WWW search engines. You surely do nothing which was not already done by other Python users as well and therefore also asked already most likely very often.

We expect that questioners try to find the solution by themselves and not asking others for making their job, see help page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you, Mofi. 

test1.py is run,

"Press any key to continue" message appears,

I press any key,

test2.py is run,

Press any key to continue message appears,

the program ends.

It feels like this is appoaching to the right direction.

But it asks "Press any key to continue" even if the program didn't have any error.

I hope it just goes on.

All I want is to see the messages while running multiple python programs sequentially.

Comment: Well, I suggested only a small code to verify if `Python.exe` is indeed a console application and therefore command `start` is not necessary at all. I updated the code to pause execution only if **Python** terminates with a return value greater or equal 1.